# 2 Adjoining Images in 1 Div Tag

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I'm using a container with a width of 960 which holds a bunch of photos. Some pics are vertical and some are horizontal. Two adjoining vertical pics, with padding, total the width of the horizontal picture which results in a nice layout of two vertical pics (next to each other) followed by one horizontal pic. Here's an example (view on desktop or phone): http://issaquahparagliding.com/2014/05-20.php

This works great for desktops and phones. However, on a tablet the vertical pics don't resize but rather re-stack, one on top of another. This results in a bunch of white space on the right. I'd like them to resize down to fit in the div and align next to each other. This graphic may help explain: http://issaquahparagliding.com/images.png

I'm stuck, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If they're stacking...it means something's adding pixels and is going > 960. Make sure to reset margin padding and border-width to 0...see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this line of CSS:

```
#pics img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

What's happening, is that the `max-width` declaration has no effect until the container is smaller than one image. So in the case where there are 2 images side by side, they don't react to the declaration because it does not apply as the container/screen is still larger than the individual image. For any images that are vertical, you will need to assign a class to them and adjust their CSS.

Example:

```
<img src="05-20/01_05-20-14%20copy.jpg">
<img class="image-half" src="05-20/02_05-20-14%20copy.jpg">
<img class="image-half" src="05-20/03_05-20-14%20copy.jpg">
<img src="05-20/04_05-20-14%20copy.jpg">

#pics img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
#pics img.image-half {
        max-width: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: AHHH, thanks. This makes sense. I've got a PHP script which displays all the images in that folder so I don't have the option of styling each image individually. Maybe I can find something that will allow me to resize them based on image width. I'll look around.

Comment: @user3684624 - you can tailor the script to check for image width (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and if below a certain amount add a class when it writes it to the DOM.

Comment: @user3684624 - also, if you found my answer useful, you should accept as it improves your answer rate (leading to more & better answers in the future)